# Can I install magento theme version 1.9 over magento 2.0.2

Tags: php, magento

Can I install magento theme version 1.9 over magento 2.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not.  Magento 2's theme format is completely different than Magento 1's.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of Magento 1.9x is entirely different than Magento 2.x so technically it's not possible to migrate a Magento 1.9.x to 2.x without actually changing the entire theme architecture. Magento 2.x is not backward compatible with Magento 1.9.x so it's NOT possible.